# Kendo UI: Can I use validator to validate row selection

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have KendoUI grid and user can select multiple rows. Before sending form data, user needs to select rows from the Kendo UI Grid. Can i use Kendo UI validator to accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK Kendo UI validations applies to single input fields. Not sure the type of validations that you want to do, but as far as it refers to single fields, it is Ok! Otherwise you would need to define a _fake_ input field which `custom` rule would do what you want. But in this last case you would probably do the same on `form` submission (i.e. invoke the validation on `form` submission and only then trigger the dataSource.transport.update by using `save` or `sync` methods on your `grid`.

Comment: I got it to work like this. Thank you!